# Start up docker container without dockerfile

Tags: docker

I've been using Dockerfiles so often that I've forgotten how to start up a new one without one.

I was reading https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/ and ofc it doesn't state how to start up a new one.

Comment: Dockerfiles are used to build images, not containers, which are like running instances of such images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
docker run -it ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

Answer (score 3):

A Dockerfile describes a Docker **image** not a **container**.

The **container** is an instance of this **image**.

If you want to run a container without building an image (which means without creating a Dockerfile), you need to use an existing image on the Docker Hub ([link here](https://hub.docker.com/explore/)).

N.B.: The Docker Hub is a Docker online repository, they are more repositories like Quay, Rancher and others.

For example, if you want to test this, you can use the *hello-world* image found on the Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/.

According to the documentation, to run a simple *hello-world* container:

> ```
> $ docker run hello-world
> ```
>
> Source: https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/

If you don't have the image locally, Docker will automatically pull it
from the web. If you want to manually pull the image you can run the
following command:

> ```
> $ docker pull hello-world
> ```
>
> To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
>
> ```
> $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
> ```
>
> Source: https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/

Comment: I was about to give myself the answer but your answer will probably help other newcomers so you get it!

Comment: Haha no problem

Comment: Maybe I'm being too petty, but -1 for copying the last two lines of your answer from the `hello-world` container's output (plus various docs around the web) without indicating that it was a quotation.

Answer (score 0):

`docker start` is used to start a stopped container which already exists and in stopped state.
If you want to start a new container use `docker run` instead. For information about `docker run` please see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/